# Convert id to sockaddr struct in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, sockets, networking

I'm working with `NSNetService`, when I try to resolve a service I get a `NSNetService` object which contains an NSArray of `ID` which describe `struct sockaddr`.

How can I convert the `id` object contained in the `NSArray` to a struct `sockaddr`. Here the code where I'm stuck.

```
- (void)netServiceDidResolveAddress:(NSNetService *)sender{

    //Obviously this row return an error...
    struct sockaddr sk = (struct sockaddr)[sender.addresses objectAtIndex:0];
    ....
}
```

Comment: "I get a NSNetService object which contains an NSArray of struct sockaddr" Now that's not quite possible. Only objects can be stored in an NSArray.

Comment: @H2CO3 the array contains a list of ID objects, but these objects contains data to describe a sockaddr. I need a way to convert from ID to sockaddr.

Comment: then write that it contains objects describing a struct sockaddr, and not that it contains structs...

Answer (score 2):

The array contains NSData objects, which you can convert to structs like:

```
struct sockaddr *sk = (struct sockaddr *)[[sender.addresses objectAtIndex:0] bytes];
```

Comment: Good call. I should add this code hasn't been compiled or tested in any way but I do hope it helps!

Comment: The struct contains a parameter called sa_data that is a C string... 
but if I try to output its content I get null... 
`NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithCString:sk->sa_data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] );`

Comment: Is it actually all null in the struct itself?